# Is there sufficient evidence to confirm additional Planet in solar system

Tags: solar-system, the-sun, planet, comets, data-analysis

I have watched this scishow episode where Hank says that astronomers believe there is another planet in our solar system.

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0thBlCkSdI)

He says that it's because how asteroids and comments are being pushed towards the sun (and us) from similar angles. **Is this true? Do astronomers really have data that confirms the 'new ninth' planet?**

**EDIT:** I did read the other related answers and articles, the way I understand this theory explained by tilt of 6 objects that could be explained by something massive enough pulling them. My question is do astronomers believe this is sufficient to confirm it that there is a planet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a ninth planet?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/is-there-a-ninth-planet)

Comment: Be *extraordinarily careful* when you say "confirm". There's not enough evidence to reach that level of confidence yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question already has muliple answers on this site...

However : Yes, astronomers DO have enough data to speculate about a possible Ninth Planet.

The orbits of six KBO are correlated, and a possible ninth planet could be the reason for those peculiar orbits. See image below for the computed results of the possible orbit of the ninth planet.:

[image]

However, since the Planet has not yet been SEEN or DETECTED, its existence is only supposed. We have nothing to prove it really exists. But if it exists, we know where it is :p

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for your answer. But what about all the other stuff in solar system shouldn't it all be pointing same way, how are these 6 objects special? I would really appreciate if you could add this to your answer, it would benefit all the future readers too.

Comment: The solar system is quite big (reaaally big), and it's all a matter of circumstences. So, point by point :

- No, all shouldn't be pointing the same way. All the objects do not have the same mass / orbits, etc. And a lot of KBO have already found their orbit. 
- Those six objects are special in a way, because their orbit have synced with the planet Nine's influence. There are for the moment six objects suspected to be under the hypothetical planet Nine's influence, but other might be discovered.

Comment: I appreciate additional explanation: basically for planet to be confirmed it has to be observed visually, and until then it's just a theory. Thanks.

Comment: You got my point ;)

Comment: Shouldn't the planet's aphelion be close to and beyond Sedna's, rather than on the opposite side?